# Finding the maximum substring for which a given predicate is true

Tags: algorithms, strings, substrings

Given a string $S$ of length $N$ and a string predicate $F$, find the maximum substring, $s$, such that $F(s) = \text{true}$.  Assume that $F$ satisfies the following:

- If $F(g) = \text{true}$, then any proper sub-string of $g$, above a certain cutoff length $L$, also evaluates true.
- Strings below the cutoff length evaluate to false

What is the best strategy to find $s$ which minimizes the function evaluations?

Naive approaches:

- Sequential search of the string $\mathcal{O}(N^2)$ function evaluations.

I suspect there must be a better way but anything I look up just sends me to Kadane's algorithm.  I would appreciate it if anyone has any references which might be useful or know the answer.

Comment: Are we also told $L$?

Comment: @j_random_hacker yes, $L$ is given in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's denote $[\exists s: F(s) \wedge |s| = x]$ as $B(x)$. First property of $F$ implies that for any $x > L$

$$B(x) \implies B(x-1)$$

Which by induction implies:

$$B(x) \implies \forall i \in [L, x] : B(i)$$

In other words, if you know that $B(x)$ is true, you don't have to examine lower values of $x$. And if $B(y)$ is false, you know that higher values of $y$ can't give you true, as it would contradict that $B(y)$ is false.

Now you can find maximal $x$ (such that $B(x)$ holds) using binary search. For each iteration of the search, $B(i)$ can be verified in $\mathcal{O}(N)$ calls to $F$: you just need to call it for every substring of fixed length $i$.

In total, this gives you $\mathcal{O}(N \log N)$ calls to $F$.

Comment: Thanks! I definitely should have thought of that in retrospect.

Comment: Could you please be more explicit on the binary search you'd perform? And why that implication means that you can do it?

Comment: @Rightleg is it better now?

Comment: "And if $B(y)$ is false, you know that higher values of $y$ can't give you true, as it would contradict that $B(y)$ is false." -- only when in addition $y > L$, and it's not 100% clear whether $L$ is actually given to us.  If it isn't, could it first be found by a similar kind of binary search, before applying the rest of your algorithm?

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yes, I assumed that $L$ is a given fixed parameter and we never probe lengths below $L$. If $L$ is not known in advance and the maximal string happens to have length $L+1$, then we can only hope for a quantum speedup of Grover's algorithm.

Comment: I meant maximal string of length $L$, not $L+1$ (not much difference anyway).

Comment: Thanks, that example helps me see that if $L$ is initially unknown, there could be just a single substring $s$ yielding $F(s) = \text{true}$, so all $O(n^2)$ substrings would need to be checked to find it.